# One or two apostrophes for two subjects in the possessive case?

Tags: apostrophe, compound-possessives

Which is correct: [Bonus question: should there be a question mark here instead of a colon?]

> The book contains **Marx** and Engels' theories about the nature of
>   society and politics.

or

> The book contains **Marx's** and Engels' theories about the nature of
>   society and politics

It seems to me that the former is more common, but I am confused here since the latter seems more logical to me (and matches what you would see in my native language Icelandic).

Comment: @tchrist Thanks, I looked but didn't find this, possibly because the title of that question is not search-optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Since  Marx and Eagles is a compound noun, you need only one 
apostrophe. As you say this a more common use than having an
apostrophe after each noun.

Tandon

Comment: You can use just one apostrophe whenever you have a noun phrase. Being a compound noun or not is not relevant.